# How to execute multiple FTP commands in single line?

Tags: unix, ftp

I need to execute multiple FTP commands in a single line at the FTP prompt. In Unix, this is possible by using ";" or "&" among others, but they don't work at the FTP prompt.

For example at the prompt, I need to run "cd /some/dir/" and then "ls -l", but on the same line, instead of different lines.

Anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending commands to shell but to the FTP server, so unix approach won't work. And FTP servers are not designed to receive multiple commands in one line: protocol specification requires sending a command and ending it with EOL.

Comment: I was beginning to wonder about that possibility. Thanks for your quick response :-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick I use as a newbie ('help yourself as you can' method :P ):

1. Write all your command lines in Excel (one command line per Excel line).
2. Then copy the whole column of commands you've written, and paste it on your FTP prompt.

The explanation is that the end of an Excel cell is considered as entering hitting, therefore your command lines will be executed successively (and successfully :D )

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but...

This option is not exactly typing multiple commands in one single FTP prompt line, but it can be useful because you can send multiple commands to FTP in a single "go", using [Here Documents](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).
I just learned about it so I can't explain much, but you can do something like:

```
ftp << limitsOfTheInstruction
user "myName" "myPassword"
cd /home/myName
ls
#another instruction
exit
limitsOfTheInstruction
```